# Javascript parameter color in Netbeans

Tags: javascript, netbeans, colors, editor

I'm trying to change the function parameters colors in netbeans 7.2, but changing the color value in 'Parameter' doesn't work at all. The color of it seems to bind to the value of 'Keyword'.

Is this a known bug?

[image]

Comment: It's likely a bug, but before reporting this to the Netbeans folks, try to check wether some other value is overriding the foreground of a parameter leading to such a conflict

Comment: Yeah I think I'm going to report it as a bug. I checked the values that it inherits from and that color is being ignored by the editor too.

Comment: Once you fill the issue, please paste its link here so that anyone who followed your question can have a look at it.

Comment: Just submitted it as a bug. http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=216462

Comment: Cool, because yesterday I've the same problem changing colors for PHP functions.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=216462

(stating the obvious, but for people who may want this question answered)